# Listing all objects that share a common variable in Javascript

Tags: javascript, oop

I'm not exactly sure how to ask this because I am just learning OOP in Javascript, but here it goes:

I am trying to be able to make a call (eventually be able to sort) for all objects with the same variable.  Here's an example below:

```
function animal(name, numLegs, option2, option3){
    this.name = name;
    this.numLegs = numLegs;
    this.option2 = option2;
    this.option3 = option3;
}

var human = new animal(Human, 2, example1, example2);
var horse = new animal(Horse, 4, example1, example2);
var dog = new animal(Dog, 4, example1, example2);
```

Using this example, I would like to be able to do a console.log() and show all animal NAMES that have 4 legs. (Should only show Horse and Dog, of course...)

I eventually want to be able to make a drop-down list or a filtered search list with this information.  I would do this with php and mySQL but I'm doing this for the sake of learning OOP in javascript.

I only ask here because I don't exactly know what to ask.
Thank you!

Comment: Seems like you're missing some quotes. Also, in JS is common practice to capitalize your constructors so you know it's a constructor and not a regular function.

Comment: Thank you, Above was just a quickly written example, I have much different information, which is working fine.  I will also take that tip on the constructor.  Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write a generic function like so:

```
function findSamePropVal(arry, prop, val)​{
    var output = [], i, len = arry.length, item;

    for (i = 0; i < len; i++){
        item = arry[i];

        if (prop in item && item[prop] == val)
            output.push(item);
    }
    return output;
}
```

You would use it like so:

```
var animals = [];
animals.push(new Animal('Human', 2, 'example1', 'example2'));
animals.push(new Animal('Horse', 4, 'example1', 'example2'));
animals.push(new Animal('Dog', 4, 'example1', 'example2'));​​​​​​
var fourLegged = findSamePropVal(animals, "numLegs", 4);
```

Here's a fiddle showing it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/cEXju/

`findSamePropVal` can also be written using Array.filter (as per @Alnitak's suggestion):

```
function findSamePropVal(arry, prop, val){    
    return arry.filter(function(ele){
        return prop in ele && ele[prop] === val;
    });
}
```

You can see the altered version of `findSamePropVal` working here: http://jsfiddle.net/cEXju/1/

Comment: good answer, except that I'd use `Array.filter()` instead of a hand-written loop.

Comment: Great answer, I am still learning everything, though I can easily read and understand what you've written.  I have to now rewrite the information that I have already input, but it is definitely for the best.

Comment: I forgot to say Thank you!  And also, I have used the Array.filter() suggestion from Alnitak.  Thank you both.  Upvotes for all!

Comment: After playing with this, I realize that this might not be the way to go for what I am trying to do.  I will eventually have 10-20 variables inside of each object and close to 300 objects.  With over 50 modifiers that could possibly effect each object.

Should I just introduce php and mySQL?

Comment: @ntgCleaner—`Array.prototype.filter` is new in ES5, so you need to allow for UAs that don't have it. And of course an index will be very much faster than a sequential search, you can do that yourself or have some other application do it for you. But you'll have to tell it what to index on.

Comment: @RobG, Thank you, I will certainly look into Array.prototype.filter.  Once I get settled learning everything I need, I will upvote this suggestion.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You need to save all `animal`s into an array, there's no way (at least I don't think there is) to get all created `animal`s.

Then just loop through the array and check for the value you want.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there's no real way to know about all those 'animal' objects you just made unless you put them somewhere. It sounds like the best way to accomplish what you want is to store them all in an array, then iterate over that array when you want to get only the ones with 4 legs.

For instance:

```
for (var i = 0; i < animals.length; ++i) {
    if (animals[i].numLegs === 4) console.log(animals[i]);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, even after editing that code to make it match up with the code above (animal instead of animalS), it says "Cannot read property 'numLegs' of undefined".  Any Ideas?

Comment: `++i` will make the first reference it in your logical operator check index `1` instead of `0`... You'll skip the first item in the array.

Comment: The idea was that you would create that array and add each of your 'animal' objects to it.

Comment: @ntgCleaner you probably don't have an array of `animals`.  You should check out Shmiddty's answer for a more complete example.

Comment: @Shmiddty no, `++i` is absolutely correct there.  Whilst your answer is better than this one, you don't appear to know how `for (...)` works...

Comment: Alnitak is correct. It doesn't matter whether it's ++i or i++, because that entire expression won't be executed until after the for-loop's body is executed. This is the way it works in most C-style for loops. (I prefer ++i to i++ when it doesn't matter, I feel that it reads better.)

Comment: @Kiyura yup.  And in most C-based languages `++i` is actually more efficient than `i++` because the former increments the value and returns it, whereas the latter retrieves the value, remembers it so it can be returned later, and _then_ increments it.  That middle phase can cause an expensive copy operation, particularly in C++.  Unless you actually require the returned value to use it in an expression it's a good habit to _always_ use the pre-increment version instead of post-increment.

Comment: Great information.  I hadn't read into it carefully enough.  Thank you for the info!